# Google Scripts - sending email based on a cell value

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is the code I am currently trying to use to implement an email based on the cell value of C2 (see screenshot of Google sheets below).

```
function amberwarning() {
  // Fetch the combined flow value
  var combflowrange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("FloodEWS").getRange("C2"); 
  var combflow = combflowrange.getValue();
  // Check combined flow value
  if (270 < combflow < 310){
    // Fetch the email address
    var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Email").getRange("A2");
    var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();
    
    // Send Alert Email.
    var subject = 'Amber warning';
    var message = 'It is possible that the Egger site will experience flooding in the coming hours. The advice is to be prepared to take action as combined river flows can increase very quickly during storms. Please keep up to date with the latest river levels for Hexham at <https://flood-warning-information.service.gov.uk/station/9006>. The latest flood warnings from the Environment Agency for Hexham are here <https://flood-warning-information.service.gov.uk/warnings?location=+hexham>. The latest MetOffice weather forecast can be found here <https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/weather/forecast/gcy2xzrne#?>. Please use all available information to inform your decision making. You will keep receiving an email as per each refresh of the latest data. The current combined flow from the North and South Tyne is' + combflow;
    
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress,subject,message);
    }
}
```

The current error message I am receiving is "The parameters (number[],String,String) don't match the method signature for MailApp.sendEmail. (line 15, file"

The idea is that:
When cell C2 is between 270 and 310, to send an email 'Amber warning'
When cell C2 is above 310 send an email 'Red warning'
When cell C2 is less than 270, no email

This will hopefully be attached to a trigger to schedule every 15 mins

Any help on how to combine the two emails (or have single codes for each email) would be greatly appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEotJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems your "emailAddress" parameter is a number array (number[]) since the error you are receiving says so.

Try using [`getValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) if it is a single address, or get the first value of [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) which is a 2D array by doing `getValues()[0]`.

Whichever you choose, assign it to your `emailAddress` variable before calling `MailApp.sendEmail()`.

Answer (score -1):

Try to follow the steps in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails)
as it explains everything clearly and how to send email through app-script

Comment: Thank you. I am just unsure how to apply the if function to it?